# What is the most computationally efficient way to index arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I've attatched the following code that shows how I look up the index value from two arrays, then choose the Z-value corresponding to that index value. The mesh_data_X and mesh_data_Y arrays are both of size (621,621), so for my application, this needs to be as fast as possible.

```
def getCurrentZ(x,y):

    # round values for res = 1 only
    x = round(x) 
    y = round(y) 

    index = int(np.where(np.logical_and(X.ravel()==x,Y.ravel()==y))[0])
    currentZ = z_data.ravel()[index]
    return currentZ
```

Currently, these X and Y arrays are seperate, but I imagine there is a way to combine them into one array, although I'm unsure if this would offer any computational advantage.

[This code shows a snippet of what the X array looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIMxr.png)

[This code shows a snippet of what the Y array looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtplV.png)

Comment: It sounds like `scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d` would be useful for you: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html

Comment: For the most part, this code is good enough for my application. I found that there were other issues that needed to be addressed first